# Export two different excel ranges to one foto in python

Tags: python, excel

I have two different ranges in excel and I want to save the ranges in one image. I use python. I tried to use union but It throws the exception "unknown.Union". Thank you for your help.

```
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        excel.visible = False

        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(self.source_path)
        ws = wb.Worksheets[0]

        #This is what I tried
        #ws.Union(ws.Range("B843:CZ847"), ws.Range("B4:CZ5")).Copy()
        img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
        imgFile = os.path.join(self.excel_target,self.excel_name)
        img.save(imgFile)
```

Comment: `Union` is a method of the Excel Application, not of a Worksheet, so `excel.Union`.